# Python panda keyerror when select column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I've created a dataframe with a .xlsx file.
I want to select one column, but I'll get a KeyError, not sure why this is the case.

```
df= pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', header=0, axis =1)

  customer_id   end customer name
0 1101          AAB
1 1102          AAC
2 1103          AAD
3 1104          AAE

df['end customer name']
KeyError: 'end customer name'

I've tried:
 - to remove the non-printable characters;
 - to use .iloc (doesn't solve what I want);
 - to convert the object to a string;
 - use thw following argument in pd.read_excel: encoding="utf-8-sig";
```

What's going on and how to fix this problem? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you check and post the output of `df.columns`? Should give you the exact column names, maybe you can find what is going on using that

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have a trailing space. Check if this is your problem.
You could also reference the second column by `df.iloc[:, 1]`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'customer_id': [1101, 1102, 1103, 1104],
    'end customer name': ['AAB', 'AAC', 'AAD', 'AAE']})

# works for me
df['end customer name']

# works by referencing the second column
df.iloc[:, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the name of columns when you are creating the dataframe:

```
df= pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', 
                  header=0, 
                  axis =1,
                  columns=['customer_id','end_customer_name')])
```

Now you have the following options to select your target column:

```
df.iloc[:,1]
df.loc[:,'end_customer_name']
df['end_customer_name']
```

Probably there are some extra invisible spaces at the original file in `.xlsx`

Comment: I get a ValueError on this one: ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['End Customer Name', 'End Customer TPID'] It seems like the whole column is not recognized. If I use the iloc function, it does say that its name is end_customer_name